# How to set the button unmovable?

Tags: java, android

In android app, I have display the number of buttons in number of rows in GridView using adapter,  If i click the button in first row right corner automatically the second row buttons are moved to first row and hide the first row buttons by second row buttons. i need to fix the solution for, the button is not move.

Anyone can give idea to fix the solution for this?

Comment: What are you doing to the item in the adapter when the button is clicked?

Comment: button is hide and get the text of the button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In GridView display the buttons inside the EditText and and set the background color as white for EditText, Now the buttons are not moving when click the button in first row on the GridView.

Answer (score 0):

**1.** Use **fixed size** `Buttons`.

**2.** The **professional way to handle it, is using**`Icons Images`.

Comment: In Image button i can't set the Text.

Comment: One canNot set text on an ImageButton, that's why it's called ImageButton but one can set the background color and an image together which is not possible in Button.. So you need to find Image that is appropriate according to the text you want on the Buttons.. they are easily available on the net.

Comment: any other way to create unmovable button using button view in gridview?

Comment: In my knowledge these two are the ways to do it...... but if you have any other suggestions to do it..., its warmly welcomed........

Comment: some one has said to use weight attribute in button view, I have try it, but it's not working, i tried many other ways, i can't fix the solution for this and i have not much experience in android.

Comment: well weight attribute is an option when the text inside the Button does Not change.... but in GUI rich applications, interactiveness is very important.. When you press a button, it usually changes its text or its background(for background changes it requires selector file), Please use fixed sized button for simple implementation, but you can try Image button using the Selector file

Comment: I have solved this problem. Display the buttons inside the TextView on GridView.

Comment: Now the buttons are not moved.